# Connect different client's GA4 & UA accounts to one BigQuery project

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, analytics

How do I connect various different client's google analytics (GA4 & UA) to one instance of Big Query? I want to store the analytics reports on bigquery & then visualise it on a unified dashboard on Looker

Answer (score 1):

1. You can set up the exports from Google Analytics to go to the same BigQuery project and transfer historical data to the same project as well.
2. Even if data is spread across multiple GCP projects, you can still query all from a single project. I would suggest you create a query that connects data from multiple sources together, you can then save it as a view and add it as a source in Looker, you can use it as a custom query in Looker or for best efficiency save the results of your query as a new reporting table that feeds into Looker.

Comment: My connections used to work, now I keep getting this error, any thoughts please:
Code 401: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See Integrating Google Sign-In into your web app  |  Authentication  |  Google Developers.

Comment: @Luka could you please elaborate more about the first point you wrote? I can't find a way how to  automatically export data from GA4 (Google account A) to BigQuery (Google Account B). I can do it easily if I export it using the same Google Account.